# compare date number and input number in shell

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell

```
www.google.com
current date: 2019-06-12 
exp date: 2019-08-14 
remaining: 63 
date mail select: 63 
not alert
```

The problem is the output of if statement didn't work as math logic.
Could it be the value of $diff and $2(input) isn't equal?
Can anyone tell me how to determine them?

```
#!/bin/bash

expi=$(echo | openssl s_client -servername $1 -connect $1:443 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -dates |grep "notAfter" | cut -d= -f2)

expi_date=$(date -d "$expi" +%Y-%m-%d)
current_date=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)

diff=$((($(date "+%s" -d "$expi_date")-$(date "+%s" -d "$current_date"))/86400))

echo $1

echo "current date: "$current_date

echo "exp date: "$expi_date

echo "remaining: "$diff

echo "date mail select: "$2

if [[$diff -eq $2]]
  then
    echo "alert"
  else
    echo "not alert"
fi
```

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer the below code:-

```
if [ "$diff" -eq "$2" ];
  then
    echo "equal"
  else
    echo "not equal"
fi
```

Comment: Oh, I miss some space on [ ]. Is this also count lol. Thank you for answer

Comment: yes, and you can use either [[ $diff -eq $2 ]] or [ "$diff" -eq "$2" ], but the condition should be separated the space

Comment: can you please rate the answer also